# Symfony: image not showing in Layout.php

Tags: image, symfony1

```
<img src="/images/example.png" alt="example" />
```

Shows up when written in the template (i.e. indexSuccess.php), but only displays the alt when used in layout.php. What is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind pasting both your layout.php and indexSuccess.php ?

Comment: There is too much code there:P If you point out what would be relevant, I may be able to just post those.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't get into the source? Also: you should be using the `image_path()` helper.

Comment: I have had this happen to me, and by changing the filename it solved the problem.  Never happened again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an image path problem. The problem was that layout was being applied to different urls: e.g. `example.com/` / `example.com/admin.php`, so the relative path of `image/example.png` did not work for all the cases. Maerlyn mentioned in the comments the use of image_path() helper function. With that the problem was solved.

TL;DR:
Use image_path() in the layout (doesn't hurt to use in templates as well, i suppose)